# How to use react-router-dom when react app resides on a path with structure: domain.com/a-path/page.php?page=param

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React app that resides on a path of the following structure:

domain.com/a-path/page.php?page=param

I want to be able to define routes for the react app, so that:

domain.com/a-path/page.php?page=param&page=page1 - redirects to page 1.

domain.com/a-path/page.php?page=param&page=page2 - redirects to page 2.

Something like:

```
<Route path={`domain.com/a-path/page.php?page=param&page=page1`}>
   Page 1
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is being served from a subdirectory on the server (as seen in your example), then `baseName` can be set to the Router via the history prop.

eg,

```
export default function App() {

const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: 'a-path'
}) 

  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/a">page 1</Route>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

//route to use will be domain.com/a-path/a

Comment: I tried `<Router basename='/wp-admin/admin.php'>...` with `<Route path="&page=members-dashboard&subpage=memberships">`. However, the route doesnt show.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Please check. @MikeHawkins